# Should shadowing be avoided in with package names and variables?

Tags: go

There's a lot of examples in test code that are shadowing package names in test libraries like testify.

For example:

```
import (
  "testing"
  "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
  "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
  assert := assert.New(t)
  require := require.New(t)
  var a string = "Hello"
  var b string = "Hello"

  assert.Equal(a, b, "The two words should be the same.")
}
```

Shouldn't it be an explicit decision and rare occurrence to override the value of a package namespace with a local variable?

```
import (
  "testing"
  "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
  "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
  assertions := assert.New(t)
  req := require.New(t)
  var a string = "Hello"
  var b string = "Hello"

  assert.Equal(a, b, "The two words should be the same.")
}
```

I'd expect the proper behavior to be aliasing the package like `pkgassert` which I doesn't feel idiomatic, or ensuring that variables are not set to the same name as the package: `assertions := assert.New(t)`.

Other examples:

- Ok: `buf := bytes.Buffer{}`
- Bad: `bytes := bytes.Buffer{}`

Note: I'm not focused on variable naming patterns, as Go tends to recommend single letter, or short variables in the narrowed scope you might use the buffer for. Assume the longer name is acceptable and desired due to the function length.

If this is a desired behavior in testing packages I'd like to know why?
It appears to violate a key principle of idiomatic Go in "no magic" and being readable.

If there are undesired side effects from this I'd like to know of that as well.
My assumption is that is means after import that any calls to the package in the same scope wouldn't work due to variable shadowing

### Edit

[Scope Shadowing in Go](https://blog.charmes.net/post/scope-shadowing-go/) was a nice read and gave some great points on usage. The main takeaway I had from this and from Stack commenters:

1. It *can* enhance readability. (I think this is probably due to Go preferring small concise naming for packages, making package names in Go variable length.)
2. [Parallel Test Issues](https://gist.github.com/posener/92a55c4cd441fc5e5e85f27bca008721#how-to-solve-this) was something I recall reading a while back. I didn't understand the recommendation to "hide" the loop variable by putting in:

   ```
    for _, tc := range tests {
        tc := tc
        t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            t.Parallel()
            // Here you test tc.value against a test function.
            // Let's use t.Log as our test function :-)
            t.Log(tc.value)
        })
    }
   ```

   }

With a better understanding of shadowing, I'm seeing this "hiding" was talking about shadowing the caller scope variable of tc by assigning inside the loop, thereby shadowing.

This seems like a good use case, though I still feel it is being "clever" rather if not commented, and violates the idiomatic Go goals of being clear and readable with no "magic".

Comment: I generally stick to `assert.Equal(t, expected, actual, msg)` for Testify assertions. `require` also has a similar API.

Comment: @CeriseLimón can you clarify what you mean? I copied that from the testify documentation directly i believe.

Comment: @ashu I'm not clear what you mean.  That's the example I provided from the testify docs. However, it implicitly shadows the package name once invoked, which seems like it could be one of those nice things in the scope of a package, or could be something to avoid in general. That's kinda what I'm asking. 

I'm wondering if anyone's been bit by this in an unforseen way.

Comment: @sheldonhull Both Testify assert and require expose a root level functions. The example above the one you copied uses that. https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.7.0/assert#Equal

Comment: The testify packages in particular have be designed for shadowing. Every package-level function also exists as a method on the respective types. Some logging packages do this as well. If there was an objectively compelling reason to not do this the Go compiler wouldn't allow it. It's a matter of style and taste.

Comment: Response to question edit: Your assumption about what it means to shadow an identifier is correct:  the shadowed identifier is not usable in the scope where the identifier is shadowed.  Some people have the opinion that shadowing reduces readability or maintainability.  Otherwise, there are no side effects of shadowing.

Comment: @CeriseLimón then can you please reopen and put that as the answer? That's pretty much what I'm looking for and have found very little on. This is useful because it is a linter flag in Goland for example, and as I'm exploring proper package design the lack of clarity on this was confusing. This is not a "opinion" question, but a design question which you answered clearly. Thank you!

Comment: https://blog.charmes.net/post/scope-shadowing-go/ Was a good article that actually showed a useful case of this that I didn't understand in past examples. In a test I've seen in parallel tests a reference to `t := t` inside a block. This article helped me understand that there is a reasonable use case for that, in that it shadows the parent scope inside the inner scope and thereby eliminates impact to the caller scope. I _think_ that's a reasonable use case for it to simplify things in tests, sound about right? Gotta revisit my variable scoping concept to make sure I'm not mixing stuff up :-)

Comment: @sheldonhull It is common to use statements like `tc := tc` to copy a value from a variable in an outer scope to a variable in the current scope.  The [FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines) recommends it.

Comment: @gopher great link. I'm familiar with those recommendation, but for clarity that's in the context of goroutines, correct? The iteration variable isn't the same in normal usage, but with goroutines this behavior is a known design issue that can't be addressed in v1 per docs to ensure compatibility, but wasn't really intended.  This article does a great job explaining this as well: https://blog.charmes.net/post/scope-shadowing-go/     Note: would appreciate an additional vote to reopen this. I think this is useful behavior to be clear on

Comment: @sheldonhull The `tc := tc` statement is required in the parallel test example because the closure runs in a goroutine.  More generally, the `tc := tc` idiom used in the context of closures where the closure can be executed after the start of the next loop iteration.

Comment: Self answer detailing summary of my findings posted, would appreciate any edits/comments so I can improve this if I got any of it wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing all the feedback and writing I've seen I'm going to summarize the findings here.

If you are investigating this behavior after seeing Go linting alerts from a tool like Goland, hopefully this answer will save you same time and make clear that it's ok, idiomatic, and only in some cases of reusing the actual package calls after initializing would any issues be experienced.

### Shadowing Package Names With Local Variables

- This is a matter of opinion, there is no official statement indicating this is considered non-idiomatic code.
- *Opinions* seem to overall lean towards avoiding shadowing unless intentionally done for clarity & readability, but this is again *opinion*, not a requirement.
- Once overridden, the package would be unavailable in that scope as the package name has been shadowed by the local variable.
- I've observed that this behavior seems more likely in Go than some languages, because Go prompts package names that are short, not multi-word, and easy to type. It seems inevitable that `assert := assert.New(t)` could result when this happens.
- Consistency, as always in matters like this, is the key. If a team determines to never shadow the package name, then `assertions := assert.New(t)` could be used, or as mentioned the package could be aliased such as `import tassert "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"`. This is an opinion standard, and either way is legal and considered idiomatic.
- In the case of testing, this is commonly done as further usage of the package after the initial variable set isn't used further. Example below using the `is` [is package](https://github.com/matryer/is). Package author [comment on this](https://github.com/matryer/is/issues/34) (again this is opinionated, but it doesn't break anything to use it with `is := is.New(t)`.

```golang
package package_test

import (
    "testing"
    "package"
    
    iz "github.com/matryer/is"
)

func TestFuncName(t *testing.T) {
    is := iz.New(t)
    
    got := FuncName()
    want := ""
    
    is.Equal(got,want) // AssertMessage
}
```

### Shadowing Behavior Can Address Goroutine Variable Issues

Shadowing is a known behavior and documented clearly in [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#channels).

> The bug is that in a Go for loop, the loop variable is reused for each iteration, so the req variable is shared across all goroutines. That's not what we want.

> It may seem odd to write `req := req` but it's legal and idiomatic in Go to do this. You get a fresh version of the variable with the same name, deliberately shadowing the loop variable locally but unique to each goroutine.

This can be solved without shadowing by passing in the variable as a parameter into the embedded func as well, simplifying the code. Both are legal and considered idiomatic per the guide.

### Shadowing for Tests

Related to this goroutine behavior, but in the context of a testing, parallel tests run in goroutines, and therefore benefit from this pattern as well.

> The tc := tc statement is required in the parallel test example because the closure runs in a goroutine. More generally, the tc := tc idiom used in the context of closures where the closure can be executed after the start of the next loop iteration - credit @gopher in comments

The gist on [Be Careful With Table Driven Tests](https://gist.github.com/posener/92a55c4cd441fc5e5e85f27bca008721#be-careful-with-table-driven-tests-and-tparallel) mentions this behavior as well in the [How To Solve This](https://gist.github.com/posener/92a55c4cd441fc5e5e85f27bca008721#how-to-solve-this).

### Detecting

The check `go vet` can check for shadowing, but is *not* considered part of the stable package, and was removed [here](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/154584/) related to [GitHub Issue 29260](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29260) and [GitHub Issue 34053](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34053).
The change seems to have been prompted for compatibility purposes due to the requirement of `unsafeptr` flag. Additional comments seem to point towards also requiring better heuristics before allowing in `go vet` without being experimental.

- [Go Vet Shadow](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/shadow/cmd/shadow)
- Instructions on running via `go vet`: [Package Variables With Instructions](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go/internal/vet#pkg-variables):

```sh
go install golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/shadow/cmd/shadow
go vet -vettool=$(which shadow)
```

For those wanting to lint this, `golangci-lint` does have an option to configure shadowing checks in the [configuration](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/configuration/) (search for `check-shadowing` as no bookmark to that text block`.

### Further Reading

- [Scope and Shadowing in Go](https://blog.charmes.net/post/scope-shadowing-go/)
- [Scopes and Closures](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines)

Comment: @CeriseLimón good point. I think I should rephrase the question to better reflect that the original question wasn't purely focused on package name shadowing but on the concept of shadowing being avoided in general. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that is awful code. While it might not be a compiler enforced rule, if I see this:

```
import "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
```

Then in that file, as far as I'm concerned, any identifier spelled `assert` is the top level import from that package, period. Anyone who breaks that pattern, in the name of being "clever" or whatever, is just asking for trouble. People's muscle memory is trained to recognize top level imports, so please, do not do stuff like this. If you want to avoid thinking of a new name, just remove some letters:

```
asrt := assert.New(t)
```

or add a letter:

```
nAssert := assert.New(t)
```

or alias the import:

```
import tAssert "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
```

Just please, do not follow the poor example given in that code.

Comment: I agree it's confusing. Do you any specific detail other than opinion on why it's bad though? Totally agree but the answer iterates basically the same concern I had. Hoping for a more specific reason to avoid this other than readability. Any edge cases or situations this caused an issue?   Note: this seems to be all over the place in testing code as well in multiple packages

Comment: @sheldonhull its just bad code style. Someone reading the code is going to think `assert` is the top level import, and will only discover thats not the case after reading **the entire file**